# Managing user specific settings in ASP MVC Views, and database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, settings

I'm rolling my own currently and tried NINI. Is there a simpler/better modular package/process to managing user settings. Where I can bubble the settings up to the user as his editable view.

Similar to app settings (I've used app setting, but they are fairly global).

1. Does ASP MVC 5 OOB natively provide a functionality to capture user
   specifics, or user object settings.
2. Or, are there any 3 party nuget packages for this
3. How do I get auto scaffolding without re-writing this for every new app

Based on @pratt I found 2 objects which might work, if they don't add overhead. I am using the older membership, but I am open to upgrading. Do I inherit from them, if so which one

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claim(v=vs.110).aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're using MVC 5, it should be safe to assume you're also using Identity. With Identity, the place for this type of thing is Claims.

Comment: Also you could look into User Profile that comes with .Net. There may help. http://forums.asp.net/t/1847086.aspx?MVC4+How+to+extend+User+Profile+ http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customize-users-profile-in-aspnet.html